# inline-block breaking the code for no obvious reason

Tags: html, css

so i'm working on my css skills and trying to get an image from a sprite from youtube, so my code was like this

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><span id="logo"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and my css is

```
    #logo {
        background: no-repeat url("http://s.ytimg.com/yts/imgbin/www-hitchhiker-vflNAOpbO.webp") -167px -205px;
        width: 72px;
        height: 30px;
        background-size: auto;
    }
```

and it won't work till i add display: inline-block; to the logo rule

so it was really confusing why do i need to set background-size to auto and why do i need display: inline-block at this certain example

Answer (score 1):

okay so after researching i've found this

default value for a span for display is inline which would ignore the width and height given at this case which why the inline block worked

the default value for background-size is auto and it's fine as we are providing the width and height of the image so it's redundant here

sorry for rushing to post rather than spending decent time researching, thanks for understanding and hope it helped :)